# Contact info of Shamoe US, a vendor on Anime Expo

Tags: conventions, anime-expo

I went to buy anime merchandise at Anime Expo this past summer and I bought it from the these vendors. I went to the Asian American Expo and met them again. I forgot to ask them for their website but they said for the upcoming Anime Expo, they will go by the vendor name Shamoe US as stated here [on Anime Expo listing page](http://www.anime-expo.org/explore/exhibitors/?letter=S).

I looked up Shamoe US in the Anime Expo 2017 list and didn't find them so I guess they went by a different name this past summer. They were the vendors in the front who for some reason, had to shut down their vendor area and leave at around the 2nd or 3rd day of Anime Expo.

Are there any contact info of Shamoe US, like their official website?

Comment: It's clearly on the list (4911) with a url. AX's interstitial thing butchers their url, but the url redirect to their Chinese Taobao site: https://shop34130744.m.taobao.com/